# JOOQ not saving changed unique key

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have a MySQL database storing values, and using JOOQ to interact with that data. Everything has worked fine for me, until I tried to change the value of a unique key. I have a table that stores groups that people can create, the owner of the group is stored as `ownerid`. I have `ownerid` set to be unique since each person can only own 1 group. The problem comes in when I try to change the ownerid (user passes ownership to another user). I set the new ownerid using `record.setOwnerId()`, and then I call `record.store()`. Once `record.store()` has completed, I am calling `record.getOwnerId()` and it is returning the correct (new) id. I should also note that there is no SQL errors that occur when this happens. The issue though, is that the SQL database never gets updated with the new value. When I do `record.refresh()`, the ownerid is set back to the previous value. Any idea why this would happen or how I would debug it? I should point out that I have verified that the new ownerid is not already in the table, and there doesn't appear to be any SQL errors being thrown.

Edit: It works completely fine if I modify the value manually, but for some reason record.store() refuses to change it

Comment: Not sure what's causing your issue without more details but here's the docs for getting better logging info from JOOQ:http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/logging/ Set that logging in place and post the results.

Comment: Can you please post the DDL of your table, as well as the precise sequence of method calls that lead to the error? It is easier to read code than text to understand what's happening